# Arrange/distribute array items uniformly

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, math, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional associative array with a `type` property. It looks like this:

```
$data = array(
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "C"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "C")
);
```

I want to rearrange it to make the items more equally distributed (with least amount of repetitive types if possible). It should look like this:

```
array(
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "C"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "C"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B")
);
```

What I've tried so far was to find the count for each type and the total:

```
$count_a = 5;
$count_b = 3;
$count_c = 2;
$total = 10;
```

And also the rate ratio for each type:

```
$ratio_a = 0.5; //(5/10)
$ratio_b = 0.3; //(3/10)
$ratio_c = 0.2; //(2/10)
```

I'm just stuck here. Should I try to make a new property `index` with a number and then sort based on it? Or maybe use modulo operator somehow? I've also tried separating the items into 3 different arrays if that makes it any easier.

Comment: your question is sorting by ratio ? or shuffling the array ?

Comment: shuffling but not just randomly. Random produces a lot of repetitive types. My goal is to have the least consecutive types.

Comment: Is the least amount of repetitive types the only requirement? So doesnt it matter if it is abcabc or abacabac?

Comment: yes. ( I understand that if there are too many of one type, repetition would be unavoidable)

Comment: The main point is: should the order be unpredictable, too?

Comment: for aaaabbcc , you want `ababacac` or `abcabcaa` ? differs to you ?

Comment: if first is correct , it is a greedy method , sort ratios , use the most ratio element till there is not such element of that type , then go for next bigest ratio and iterate over all element

Comment: `abcabcaa` would work better since the repeat pattern is longer. The order doesn't matter.

Comment: lemme write it in answer ...

Comment: my idea based on making recursive function to make such string

Comment: Ok, it seems to be the case you want it like a zipper with repeating pattern. Correct?

Comment: yes. I guess you could say that.

Comment: If 'ababacabac' would work for you too, you could try a rule like 'pick one from the biggest heap, different from the last pick'

Comment: The question needs more precision. In the question it says *"with least amount of repetitive types if possible"*, but in comments you express preference for getting repeating patterns at the cost of having repeated types at the end. You should clarify *in the question* on what you consider a best solution, removing all ambiguity.

Comment: Check the answers and give some feedback.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks a lot for the help. I truly appreciate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a sorted array of sorted types and do iterative walk through it step by step changing selected type by one.

```
$data = array(
  array( "name" => "SomeName1", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName2", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName3", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName4", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName5", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName6", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName7", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName8", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName9", "type" => "C"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName0", "type" => "C")
);

$dataSorted = array();
$counts = array();

foreach($data as $elem) {
    // just init values for a new type
    if(!isset($counts[$elem['type']])) {
        $counts[$elem['type']] = 0;
        $dataByType[$elem['type']] =  array();
    }

    // count types
    $counts[$elem['type']]++;

    // save it to grouped array
    $dataByType[$elem['type']][] =  $elem;
}

// sort it to A=>5, B=>3 C=>2
arsort($counts, SORT_NUMERIC);

// get sorted types as an array
$types = array_keys($counts);

// index will be looped 0 -> count($types) - 1 and then down to 0 again
$currentTypeIndex = 0;

// make a walk on sorted array. First get the most popular, then less popular etc.
// when all types are added, repeat
while(count($dataSorted) < count($data)) {
    $currentType = $types[$currentTypeIndex];

    // skip adding if we ran out this type
    if($counts[$currentType]) {
        // pop an element of selected type
        $dataSorted[] = array_pop($dataByType[$currentType]);

        // decrease counter
        $counts[$currentType]--;
    }

    // choose next type
    $currentTypeIndex = (++$currentTypeIndex)%count($types);
}

print_r($dataSorted);
```

The code outputs elements in order of ABCABCABAA.

UPD. trailing doubling takes place in case `count(maxtype)` > `count(nexttype) + 1`

Comment: Ivan, maybe I'm missing something but your solution shows doubled `A` here: https://3v4l.org/uS5ru. And will show even more if we increase amount of them.

Comment: That for author's comment `abcabcaa would work better since the repeat pattern is longer`. Looks like length of a pattern is more important than double-A. 
Doubling takes place if `count(maxtype)` > `count(nexttype) + 1`. It is not clear, what is the appropriate intention.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works great! Sorry about the confusion at first.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution that avoids repeating patterns whenever possible.

For `AAAAABBBCC` it would generate `ABABABACAC`;

For `AAAAABBBCCC` it would generate `ABCABABACAC`;

Apart from sorting by type count, it runs in linear time (it accepts an unsorted data array). The result is in `$distributed_data`. For explanation see below.

### Code

```
$data = array(
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
);

$distributed_data = array();
$counts = array();
$size = sizeof($data);

// Count values
foreach ($data as $entry) {
  $counts[$entry["type"]] = isset($counts[$entry["type"]]) ? $counts[$entry["type"]] + 1 : 1;
}

// Set counter
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
  $data[$i]["count"] = $counts[$data[$i]["type"]];
}

// Sort by count
usort($data, function($entry1, $entry2) {
    return $entry2["count"] <=> $entry1["count"];
});

// Generate the distributed array
$max_length = $data[0]["count"];
$rows = ceil($size / $max_length);
$last_row = ($size - 1) % $max_length + 1;
$row_cycle = $rows;

$row = 0;
$col = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
  if ($i == $rows * $last_row) {
    $row_cycle -= 1;
  }

  $distributed_data[$i] = $data[$row * $max_length + $col];

  $row = ($row + 1) % $row_cycle;
  if ($row == 0) {
    $col++;
  }
}
```

### Explanation

First, order the entries according to the number of repetitions each type has. E.g. `CBBCAAB` becomes `BBBAACC`.

Then imagine a table that has as many columns as the most frequent occurrence (e.g. if you have `AAAABBCC`, the most frequent occurrence would be 4, and the table would have 4 columns).

Then write all entries into the table, left to right, jumping to new row as necessary.

E.g. for `AAAAABBBCCC` you would get a table like this:

[image: Table example]

To generate the final distributed array just read the entries top-down, shifting to a new column as necessary.

In the above example, you would get `ABCABABACAC`.

The only way to get repeating entries is to either have two of the same characters in a column, or meet the same character when shifting to a column on the right.

The first scenario can't happen because a character group would need to wrap around and this can't happen, because there is no character group longer than the number of columns (that's how we defined the table).

The second scenario can only happen when the second row isn't full. E.g. `AAAABB` leaves the second row with two empty cells.

Answer (score 5):

Algorithm:

```
function distribute($data) {
    $groups = [];
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $groups[$row['type']][] = $row;
    }
    $groupSizes = array_map('count', $groups);
    asort($groupSizes);

    $result = [];
    foreach ($groupSizes as $type => $groupSize) {
        if (count($result) == 0) {
            $result = $groups[$type];
        } elseif (count($result) >= count($groups[$type])) {
            $result = merge($result, $groups[$type]);
        } else {
            $result = merge($groups[$type], $result);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

function merge($a, $b) {
    $c1 = count($a);
    $c2 = count($b);
    $result = [];
    $i1 = $i2 = 0;
    while ($i1 < $c1) {
        $result[] = $a[$i1++];
        while ($i2 < $c2 && ($i2+1)/($c2+1) < ($i1+1)/($c1+1)) {
            $result[] = $b[$i2++];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The main idea is to split the data into groups and merge the next smallest group into the result (starting with an empty result).

While merging two arrays the items are sorted by a float key, which is calculated (on the flow) in this line

```
while ($i2 < $c2 && ($i2+1)/($c2+1) < ($i1+1)/($c1+1))
```

as

```
floatKey = (index + 1) / (groupSize + 1)
```

(This part however can be improved, so the distance to the "corners" (`0` and `1`) would be half as big as the distance between two items).

On tie the item from the bigger group comes first.

Example: Merging `AAAA` and `BB` the keys for `A` would be `0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8` anf for `B` - `0.33, 0.66`. The result would be

```
A(0.2), B(0.33), A(0.4), A(0.6), B(0.66), A(0.8)
```

Tests:

```
$testData = [
    'AAAAABBBCC',
    'AAAAABBBCCC',
    'ABBCCC',
    'AAAAAABBC',
    'AAAAAABBBBCCD',
    'AAAAAAAAAABC',
    'hpp',
    'stackoverflow',
    'ACCD', // :-)
];

$results = [];

foreach ($testData as $dataStr) {
    $a = str_split($dataStr);
    $data = [];
    foreach ($a as $type) {
        $data[] = ['type' => $type];
    }
    $result = distribute($data);
    $resultStr = implode(array_column($result, 'type'));
    $results[$dataStr] = $resultStr;
}
var_export($results);
```

Test results:

```
'AAAAABBBCC' => 'BACABACABA',
'AAAAABBBCCC' => 'CABACABACAB',
'ABBCCC' => 'BCACBC',
'AAAAAABBC' => 'ABAACAABA',
'AAAAAABBBBCCD' => 'BACABADABACAB',
'AAAAAAAAAABC' => 'AAACAAAABAAA',
'hpp' => 'php',
'stackoverflow' => 'sakeofwlrovct',
'ACCD' => 'ACDC',
```

Test demo: http://rextester.com/BWBD90255

You can easily add more test cases to the demo.

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = array(
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "C"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "C")
);

//make seperate arrays
echo "<pre>";
foreach($data as $val){

    ${$val["type"]}[]=$val["name"];
    $types[]=$val['type'];
}

$types=array_unique($types);

//make ratio
foreach($types as $val){
    $cnt[]=count($$val);
}
//find maximum from ratio
echo $max=max($cnt);
echo $min=min($cnt);


for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
    foreach($types as $val){

            if(isset($$val[$i])){
                $new_array[]=array("name"=>$$val[$i],"type"=>$val);
            }
        }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ju2k-abte

Explanation

> ```
>      - Step 1: Make separate array   
>
>      - Step 2: Count all array and find out the ratio
>
>
>
>      - Step 3: Iterate with array with maximum ratio value
>      - Step 4: Make array with same index together  and merge them in multidimensional
>        array
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
<?php
     $data = array(
        array( "name" => "SomeName 1", "type" => "A"),
        array( "name" => "SomeName 2", "type" => "A"),
        array( "name" => "SomeName 3", "type" => "A"),
        array( "name" => "SomeName 4", "type" => "A"),
        array( "name" => "SomeName 5", "type" => "A"),
        array( "name" => "SomeName 6", "type" => "B"),
        array( "name" => "SomeName 7", "type" => "B"),
        array( "name" => "SomeName 8", "type" => "B"),
        array( "name" => "SomeName 9", "type" => "C"),
        array( "name" => "SomeName 10", "type" => "C")
        );
        $result     = array();
        $typeArr    = array();
        $countArr   = array();
        $ratioArr   = array();

        foreach($data as $t){
           $typeArr[$t['type']][]   = $t;
           $countArr[$t['type']]    = count($typeArr[$t['type']]);
           $ratioArr[$t['type']]        = $countArr[$t['type']]/ count($data);
         }

        arsort($countArr);
        $countArrIndex = array_keys($countArr);
        $maxKeyCount = 0 ;$exceptMaxKey = 1;
        $exceptMaxKeyCount=0;
        for($i = 0; $i<count($data); $i++){
            if($i%2 != 0 ){
                 $result[$i]    =  $typeArr[$countArrIndex[$exceptMaxKey]][$exceptMaxKeyCount];
                 if($exceptMaxKey == (count($typeArr)-1)){
                     $exceptMaxKey  = 1;
                     $exceptMaxKeyCount++;
                 }else{
                     $exceptMaxKey++;
                 }

           }else{
               $result[$i]  =  $typeArr[$countArrIndex[0]][$maxKeyCount];
              $maxKeyCount ++;
           }
           }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        $countArr['total'] = count($data);
        print_r($countArr);
        print_r($ratioArr);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Check this exact output of what you want,

```
$data = array(
    array("name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
    array("name" => "SomeName1", "type" => "A"),
    array("name" => "SomeName2", "type" => "A"),
    array("name" => "SomeName3", "type" => "A"),
    array("name" => "SomeName4", "type" => "A"),
    array("name" => "SomeName5", "type" => "B"),
    array("name" => "SomeName6", "type" => "B"),
    array("name" => "SomeName7", "type" => "B"),
    array("name" => "SomeName8", "type" => "C"),
    array("name" => "SomeName9", "type" => "C"),
);
// getting all counts
$type = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($type) || $type != $value['type']) {
        $type    = $value['type'];
        $counter = 0;
    }
    $temp[$value['type']] = ++$counter;
}
/**
 * array search with multiple values
 *
 * @param  array  $parents  input array
 * @param  array  $searched search array
 *
 * @return int    key of found items
 */
function multidimensional_search($parents, $searched)
{
    if (empty($searched) || empty($parents)) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($parents as $key => $value) {
        $exists = true;
        foreach ($searched as $skey => $svalue) {
            $exists = ($exists && isset($parents[$key][$skey]) && $parents[$key][$skey] == $svalue);
        }
        if ($exists) {return $key;}
    }
    return false;
}
$output_array = [];
$first_value  = current($temp);
$first_key    = key($temp);
$flag         = 0;
$junkArr      = array_column($data, 'type', 'name');
$remember_me  = 0;
$incr         = 0;
end($temp);
$end_item = key($temp);
reset($temp);
$remember_index = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $output_array[] = $data[multidimensional_search($data, ['name' => key($junkArr), 'type' => current($junkArr)])];
    if ($temp[$first_key] > 0) {
        $temp[$first_key] = --$first_value;
    }
    $direction = (empty($direction) || $direction == 'reverse' ? "forward" : "reverse");
    for ($k = 0; $k <= $remember_me; $k++) {
        if ($direction == 'forward') {
            next($temp);
        } else {
            prev($temp);
            if ($k == 0) {
                $incr = $remember_me + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    $remember_me = $incr;
    if ($remember_me == count($temp) - 1) {
        $remember_me = 0;
    }
    $first_key   = key($temp);
    $first_value = current($temp);
    if (in_array($first_key, $junkArr)) {
        $saved_key = key($junkArr);
        reset($junkArr);
        while ($first_key !== current($junkArr)) {
            next($junkArr);
        }
        unset($junkArr[$saved_key]);
    }
}
pr($output_array);
die;
```

Map it the way you like.

Give it a try, it will work.

What I am trying to do is,

1. fetching all counter of all types
2. then I am mapping it with name and type so as we can identify uniquely by name
3. then I am using pointer variable on temp to track around the things w.r.t count left for each type
4. I am populating output array with unique key value pair for every type from top to bottom.
5. I used junkarray to move pointer around with the help of count remaining.

Comment: Almost there :}

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to reorder the list to minimize repetition, once you have the counts of each type, like

```
$count_a = 5;
$count_b = 3;
$count_c = 2;
$total = 10;
```

then you can just select the most populous type, and select a line from that type, and place that at position 0 in the list you're creating. Then decrement the count for that type, and select from the most populous type that wasn't just selected. Continue until only one type remains, and place those on the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation based on the idea on [naktinis's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42192640/2677334):

```
// split data into arrays of distinct type
$buckets = array_reduce($data, function($result, $item) {
    $type = $item["type"];
    if (!isset($result[$type])) {
        $result[$type] = [];
    }
    array_push($result[$type], $item);
    return $result;
}, []);
// sort buckets by size
usort($buckets, function($a, $b) {
    return count($b) - count($a);
});
// merge buckets to single array sorted by type
// and split to chunks of size of the largest bucket
$table = array_chunk(array_merge(...$buckets), count($buckets[0]));
// compute final array by merging each column
$result = [];
foreach (array_keys($table[0]) as $i) {
    $result = array_merge($result, array_column($table, $i));
}
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/IJrQH).

Answer (score 0):

### I am not sure my script using method is correct or not , Please check once

```
<?php

/* multidimensional array */
$data = array(
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "A"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "B"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "C"),
  array( "name" => "SomeName", "type" => "C")
);

/* Assign blank arrays for further use */
$a_array = $b_array = $c_array = $returnArray = array();

$count = count($data); // count array 

$x = $y = $z = $m = $a = $b = $c = 0;   // assiging variable with value 0 

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    if($data[$i]['type'] == "A")
    {
        $a_array[$x]["name"] = $data[$i]["name"];
        $a_array[$x]["type"] = $data[$i]["type"];
        $x++ ;
    }
    elseif($data[$i]['type'] == "B")
    {
        $b_array[$y]["name"] = $data[$i]["name"];
        $b_array[$y]["type"] = $data[$i]["type"];
        $y++ ;
    }
    elseif($data[$i]['type'] == "C")
    {
        $c_array[$z]["name"] = $data[$i]["name"];
        $c_array[$z]["type"] = $data[$i]["type"];
        $z++ ;
    }
}

for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
{
    if($j == 0 || $j % 2 == 0)
    {
        $returnArray[$m]["name"] = $a_array[$a]["name"];
        $returnArray[$m]["type"] = $a_array[$a]["type"];
        $a++ ;
    }
    else
    {
        if($j == 3 || $j == 7)
        {
            $returnArray[$m]["name"] = $c_array[$c]["name"];
            $returnArray[$m]["type"] = $c_array[$c]["type"];
            $c++ ;
        }
        else
        {
            $returnArray[$m]["name"] = $b_array[$b]["name"];
            $returnArray[$m]["type"] = $b_array[$b]["type"];
            $b++ ;
        }
    }

    $m++ ;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_R($returnArray);

?>
```

**Thanks *:)***

Answer (score 0):

**OMG** so many huge functions here.

**requested ABAC ABAC ...**
done:

```
function sortTypes(array $data, array $types)
{
    $result = [];
    while (!empty($data)) {
        $currentType = current($types);
        if (!next($types)) {
            reset($types);
        }
        foreach ($data as $key => $array) {
            if ($array['type'] === $currentType) {
                $result[$key] = $array;
                unset($data[$key]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$types = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C']; // gets sorted by this pattern
$result = sortTypes($data, $types);
```

Test:

```
var_export($result);
// OUT: 
[
    0 => [
        'name' => 'SomeName',
        'type' => 'A',
    ],
    5 => [
        'name' => 'SomeName',
        'type' => 'B',
    ],
    1 => [
        'name' => 'SomeName',
        'type' => 'A',
    ],
    8 => [
        'name' => 'SomeName',
        'type' => 'C',
    ],
    2 => [
        'name' => 'SomeName',
        'type' => 'A',
    ],
    6 => [
        'name' => 'SomeName',
        'type' => 'B',
    ],
    3 => [
        'name' => 'SomeName',
        'type' => 'A',
    ],
    9 => [
        'name' => 'SomeName',
        'type' => 'C',
    ],
    4 => [
        'name' => 'SomeName',
        'type' => 'A',
    ],
    7 => [
        'name' => 'SomeName',
        'type' => 'B',
    ],
]
```